# Can't install pytorch3d

Tags: pytorch, torchvision, pytorch3d

I work in WSL on VS Code.
I tried to install pytroch3d using the command: conda install pytorch3d -c pytorch3d
And got an error...

```
Retrieving notices: ...working... done
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: unsuccessful attempt using repodata from current_repodata.json, retrying with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: - 
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versionsThe following specifications were found to be incompatible with your system:

  - feature:/linux-64::__cuda==12.3=0
  - feature:/linux-64::__glibc==2.35=0
  - feature:|@/linux-64::__cuda==12.3=0
  - feature:|@/linux-64::__glibc==2.35=0
  - pytorch3d -> pytorch==2.0.1 -> __cuda[version='>=11.8']
  - pytorch3d -> torchvision[version='>=0.5'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17,<3.0.a0']

Your installed version is: 2.35
```

Before that I installed pytorch using command: conda install pytorch==2.0.1 torchvision==0.15.2 torchaudio==2.0.2 pytorch-cuda=11.8 -c pytorch -c nvidia

Conda list:

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                        main  
_openmp_mutex             5.1                       1_gnu  
blas                      1.0                         mkl  
bleach                    6.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
bokeh                     3.3.4                    pypi_0    pypi
brotli-python             1.0.9           py310h6a678d5_7  
bzip2                     1.0.8                h7b6447c_0  
ca-certificates           2023.12.12           h06a4308_0  
certifi                   2023.11.17      py310h06a4308_0  
cffi                      1.16.0          py310h5eee18b_0  
charset-normalizer        2.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
chumpy                    0.70                     pypi_0    pypi
contourpy                 1.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
cryptography              41.0.7          py310hdda0065_0  
cuda-cudart               11.8.89                       0    nvidia
cuda-cupti                11.8.87                       0    nvidia
cuda-libraries            11.8.0                        0    nvidia
cuda-nvrtc                11.8.89                       0    nvidia
cuda-nvtx                 11.8.86                       0    nvidia
cuda-runtime              11.8.0                        0    nvidia
cycler                    0.12.1                   pypi_0    pypi
dataclasses               0.8                pyh6d0b6a4_7  
dominate                  2.9.1                    pypi_0    pypi
et-xmlfile                1.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
exceptiongroup            1.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
ffmpeg                    4.3                  hf484d3e_0    pytorch
filelock                  3.13.1          py310h06a4308_0  
fonttools                 4.47.2                   pypi_0    pypi
freetype                  2.12.1               h4a9f257_0  
freia                     0.2                      pypi_0    pypi
fvcore                    0.1.5.post20221221    pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
giflib                    5.2.1                h5eee18b_3  
gmp                       6.2.1                h295c915_3  
gmpy2                     2.1.2           py310heeb90bb_0  
gnutls                    3.6.15               he1e5248_0  
idna                      3.4             py310h06a4308_0  
importlib-resources       6.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
iniconfig                 2.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
intel-openmp              2021.4.0          h06a4308_3561  
iopath                    0.1.9              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jinja2                    3.1.3           py310h06a4308_0  
jpeg                      9e                   h5eee18b_1  
kiwisolver                1.4.5                    pypi_0    pypi
kornia                    0.7.1                    pypi_0    pypi
lame                      3.100                h7b6447c_0  
lcms2                     2.12                 h3be6417_0  
ld_impl_linux-64          2.38                 h1181459_1  
lerc                      3.0                  h295c915_0  
libcublas                 11.11.3.6                     0    nvidia
libcufft                  10.9.0.58                     0    nvidia
libcufile                 1.8.1.2                       0    nvidia
libcurand                 10.3.4.107                    0    nvidia
libcusolver               11.4.1.48                     0    nvidia
libcusparse               11.7.5.86                     0    nvidia
libdeflate                1.17                 h5eee18b_1  
libffi                    3.4.4                h6a678d5_0  
libgcc-ng                 11.2.0               h1234567_1  
libgomp                   11.2.0               h1234567_1  
libiconv                  1.16                 h7f8727e_2  
libidn2                   2.3.4                h5eee18b_0  
libnpp                    11.8.0.86                     0    nvidia
libnvjpeg                 11.9.0.86                     0    nvidia
libpng                    1.6.39               h5eee18b_0  
libstdcxx-ng              11.2.0               h1234567_1  
libtasn1                  4.19.0               h5eee18b_0  
libtiff                   4.5.1                h6a678d5_0  
libunistring              0.9.10               h27cfd23_0  
libuuid                   1.41.5               h5eee18b_0  
libwebp                   1.3.2                h11a3e52_0  
libwebp-base              1.3.2                h5eee18b_0  
linkify-it-py             2.0.3                    pypi_0    pypi
llvmlite                  0.42.0                   pypi_0    pypi
lz4-c                     1.9.4                h6a678d5_0  
markdown                  3.5.2                    pypi_0    pypi
markdown-it-py            3.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
markupsafe                2.1.5                    pypi_0    pypi
matplotlib                3.8.2                    pypi_0    pypi
mdit-py-plugins           0.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
mdurl                     0.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
mkl                       2021.4.0           h06a4308_640  
mkl-service               2.4.0           py310h7f8727e_0  
mkl_fft                   1.3.1           py310hd6ae3a3_0  
mkl_random                1.2.2           py310h00e6091_0  
mpc                       1.1.0                h10f8cd9_1  
mpfr                      4.0.2                hb69a4c5_1  
mpmath                    1.3.0           py310h06a4308_0  
ncurses                   6.4                  h6a678d5_0  
nettle                    3.7.3                hbbd107a_1  
networkx                  3.1             py310h06a4308_0  
numba                     0.59.0                   pypi_0    pypi
numpy                     1.23.1          py310h1794996_0  
numpy-base                1.23.1          py310hcba007f_0  
opencv-python             4.9.0.80                 pypi_0    pypi
openh264                  2.1.1                h4ff587b_0  
openjpeg                  2.4.0                h3ad879b_0  
openpyxl                  3.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
openssl                   3.0.13               h7f8727e_0  
packaging                 23.2                     pypi_0    pypi
pandas                    2.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
panel                     1.3.8                    pypi_0    pypi
param                     2.0.2                    pypi_0    pypi
pillow                    10.0.1          py310ha6cbd5a_0  
pip                       23.3.1          py310h06a4308_0  
pluggy                    1.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
portalocker               2.3.0           py310h06a4308_1  
pycocotools               2.0.7                    pypi_0    pypi
pycparser                 2.21               pyhd3eb1b0_0  
pymp                      0.0.6                    pypi_0    pypi
pyopenssl                 23.2.0          py310h06a4308_0  
pyparsing                 3.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pysocks                   1.7.1           py310h06a4308_0  
pytest                    8.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
python                    3.10.13              h955ad1f_0  
python-dateutil           2.8.2                    pypi_0    pypi
pytorch                   2.0.1           py3.10_cuda11.8_cudnn8.7.0_0    pytorch
pytorch-cuda              11.8                 h7e8668a_5    pytorch
pytorch-mutex             1.0                        cuda    pytorch
pytz                      2024.1                   pypi_0    pypi
pyviz-comms               3.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pyyaml                    6.0.1           py310h5eee18b_0  
readline                  8.2                  h5eee18b_0  
requests                  2.28.1                   pypi_0    pypi
scipy                     1.12.0                   pypi_0    pypi
setuptools                68.2.2          py310h06a4308_0  
six                       1.16.0             pyhd3eb1b0_1  
sqlite                    3.41.2               h5eee18b_0  
sympy                     1.12            py310h06a4308_0  
tabulate                  0.9.0           py310h06a4308_0  
termcolor                 2.1.0           py310h06a4308_0  
tk                        8.6.12               h1ccaba5_0  
tomli                     2.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
torchtriton               2.0.0                     py310    pytorch
torchvision               0.15.2              py310_cu118    pytorch
tornado                   6.4                      pypi_0    pypi
tqdm                      4.65.0          py310h2f386ee_0  
trimesh                   4.1.3                    pypi_0    pypi
typing-extensions         4.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
typing_extensions         4.9.0           py310h06a4308_1  
tzdata                    2023.4                   pypi_0    pypi
uc-micro-py               1.0.2                    pypi_0    pypi
urllib3                   1.26.13                  pypi_0    pypi
webencodings              0.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
wheel                     0.41.2          py310h06a4308_0  
xyzservices               2023.10.1                pypi_0    pypi
xz                        5.4.5                h5eee18b_0  
yacs                      0.1.6              pyhd3eb1b0_1  
yaml                      0.2.5                h7b6447c_0  
zlib                      1.2.13               h5eee18b_0  
zstd                      1.5.5                hc292b87_0
```

Then tried to install pytorch3d. And I saw the problem with cuda version.

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versionsThe following specifications were found to be incompatible with your system:

  - feature:/linux-64::__cuda==12.3=0
  - feature:/linux-64::__glibc==2.35=0
  - feature:|@/linux-64::__cuda==12.3=0
  - feature:|@/linux-64::__glibc==2.35=0
  - pytorch3d -> pytorch==2.0.1 -> __cuda[version='>=11.8']
  - pytorch3d -> torchvision[version='>=0.5'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17,<3.0.a0']

Your installed version is: 12.3
```

I checked the version of cuda using command:

```
nvcc --version
```

It showed me version 12.3

Then I installed cuda 11.8 from nvidia official site. And restarded the computer (just in case).
But it didn't help. And i still see this...

```
  - feature:/linux-64::__cuda==12.3=0
  - feature:/linux-64::__glibc==2.35=0
  - feature:|@/linux-64::__cuda==12.3=0
  - feature:|@/linux-64::__glibc==2.35=0
  - pytorch3d -> pytorch==2.0.1 -> __cuda[version='>=11.8']
  - pytorch3d -> torchvision[version='>=0.5'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17,<3.0.a0']

Your installed version is: 2.35
```